# MVVM WPF properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In my WPF project a `DataGrid` is bound to a collection. When `DataGrid` row selection changes the corresponding `TextBox`, should get updated. The `DataGrid` selected item is bound to a property

```
SelectedItem="{Binding CardType.SelectedCard}"
```

and corresponding  Text box is bound

```
Text="{Binding CardType.SelectedCard.LimitBalance}"
```

so when a selected item is changed, my text box will get updated.

DataGrid

```
<DataGrid 
   x:Name="dtGridSearch" 
   Margin="0,0,8,0" 
   AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   GridLinesVisibility="None" 
   SelectionMode="Single" 
   CanUserAddRows="False" 
   BorderThickness="0" 
   RowHeaderWidth="0" 
   RowStyle="{StaticResource TCAS_RowStyle}" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding CardType.Cards}" 
   SelectedItem="{Binding CardType.SelectedCard}"  
   SelectionChanged="dtGridSearchSelectionChanged">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CardCode"  Binding="{Binding CardId}"  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="150" CanUserResize="False" >
         <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbCardCode" Text=""/>
         </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
      </DataGridTextColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CardName"  Binding="{Binding CardDescription}"  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="250" CanUserResize="False" >
         <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbCardName" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
         </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
      </DataGridTextColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ProductCode"  Binding="{Binding ProductTypeCode}"  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="150" CanUserResize="False" >
         <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbProductCode" Text=""/>
         </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
      </DataGridTextColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Limitbalance"  Binding="{Binding LimitBalance}"  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100*" CanUserResize="False" >
         <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbLimitbalance" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
         </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
      </DataGridTextColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

TextBox

```
<TextBox 
    x:Name="txtLimitbalance" 
    Grid.Row="3" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Margin="16,0,0,0" 
    Style="{StaticResource  TMS_TextBox_Base1}" 
    Text="{Binding CardType.SelectedCard.LimitBalance, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    MaxLength="45" 
    Height="24" 
    Width="210" 
    TabIndex="4" 
    PreviewKeyDown="txtLimitbalancePreviewKeyDown"/>
<CheckBox 
    x:Name="chkused" 
    Grid.Row="3" 
    Grid.Column="2"  
    Margin="16,4,0,8" 
    Content="{Binding Resources.NPUsed}" 
    IsChecked="{Binding CardType.SelectedCard.ActiveStatus, Mode=TwoWay}"
    TabIndex="5"/>
```

User update the text box to a different value from original value , so one property of row1 is updated ,now user selected the different row i.e row`enter code here`2 from datagrid. again user selected the row1 so it is dispalying updated value not original value. I want to display original value only.

Comment: Can you use a `TextBlock` instead of a `TextBox` so they can't edit the value?

Comment: in your MVVM structure, did you define a class (ViewModel type) which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for the class(View type)?

Comment: If you always want the original value, what is the point of the textbox?  If its just for display, then the textbox should be read-only and the mode should be OneWay

Comment: The text box is to edit but the text edited should be changed to original value on row change,

Comment: Can you post your view model code? It sound like you are binding the text box to the same item as the data grid is bound to. Doing this will change it in both places because you are editing the same object.